# Different test results from Instrument and command line

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I　have a automated test script written in `UIAutomation`.  If I run it from the Instrument, all tests are passed.  If I run it from the command line, one of the test case will fail and result in the termination of test script running.

The failing test case is about triggering a `UIAActivityIndictor` and then show an Alert window.

I did some search online, and people are saying that the command line is faster than the Instrument.  Sometimes, you need to make sure the `UIAElement` is valid.  However, in my case, at that test case, it seems the command line lost the `UIAElements` hierarchy of the app.  The result of logElementTree is only the target and the app, no window at all.  And the UI seems frozen.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried adding a delay right before the failing line? In my tests I had to purposely slow down some sections because the automation tool was fast enough to catch the app in a transition state like when a dialog was still disappearing. The console may have sped your code up fast enough to cause this kind of issue.

Comment: Yes, I added the delay.  But the issue is that somehow the test lost the whole view hierarchy.

Comment: I've noticed a lot of erratic behavior with Instruments but all of mine were time related issues so I was hopeful that maybe it'd word for you too!

Comment: Is the alert window from iOS or from your application?  Certain actions can mess up the `target` and `mainWindow` references.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with similar issues. When UI is completely frozen it means that application has been put in infinite loop. In my case NSLog with huge output was the cause. To check that:
1) put really big sleep at some point in your script
2) run the script
3) attach xcode to the app: debug->attach to a process->your app's process
4) wait until freeze happen. Make sure of it manually
5) in xcode press pause execution
6) now you can see in stacktrace where the app is hanging